# Is my Citrus Sugar still good?

Tags: food-safety, storage-method, sugar

So I made citrus sugar about a month ago... and in the [process of deciding how to give it away](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9746/should-i-leave-the-peel-in-citrus-sugar) I realized that I have been storing it wrong. During the last month it has been stored in a dark area in my house that is kept around or below 21 degrees celsius. Based on the previous question I learned that I should keep this in the fridge. If I transfer my Citrus Sugar to the fridge will it still be good? I only ask this because [this question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/5263/does-white-sugar-have-a-shelf-life) mentions that sugar used to be used for preservation and my Citrus Sugar is mostly sugar and is kept in a sealed jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never made Citrus Sugar, but I certainly have made vanilla sugar.  Crystaline sugar soaks up the moisture, so if bacteria or mold were to invade the pot, it would be dehydrated quickly and wouldn't survive, let alone thrive.  They need a good bit of moisture to reproduce.  I've never had a problem with my vanilla sugar and it doesn't take long for the vanilla beans to turn into little vanilla toothpicks.